# How can I avoid the Visual Studio 2010 message "(Build Only Project) which is not currently available"?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've bound the key combination Ctrl+B, Ctrl+B to the Build Only Project command. I have a solution with a web application, several business layer dlls, and several Silverlight projects. I want to build the Silverlight project I'm working in with the key stroke to avoid building everything everytime. I'm growing tired of having to right click on the project, then clicking build everytime. Why isn't Build only project available and how can I make it so?

Comment: shift+f6 does this for me, do you have something peculiar project setup ?

Comment: I do have projects in the "Solution folders" and it is a pretty big project, but I wouldn't think that would stop it from working.

Comment: I just tried it on a small test project and got the same message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If finally revisited this and realized that I could create a macro in Visual Studio 2010. Here is the macro script (very basic). Maybe it will help someone. I mapped it to ctrl + 6, 6 to avoid to much movement from my mouse.

```
Sub BuildCurrentProject()
  DTE.ExecuteCommand("ClassViewContextMenus.ClassViewProject.Build")
End Sub
```

This works well with the "Solution Navigator" from the Visual Studio Productivity Power Tools extension